# Spring-security, 404 errors should be 401 or 403 in restricted folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have this configuration in spring-security.xml :

```
<http 
    create-session="stateless" 
    realm="Protected API"
    auto-config="true"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/auth/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />    
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/auth/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />   
    <http-basic/>   
</http>
```

So any user can access to */api/mypublicservice1*. Registered users can access to */api/auth/userservice2*. And only admins have access to */api/auth/admin/adminservice3*. That's working.

But I want a better way to handle 404 requests into restricted folders.

For instance :

- For an anonymous user, */api/auth/userservice2* returns **401**
- For an anonymous user, */api/auth/thispagedoesntexist* returns 404 ; instead it should return **401**
- For a non-admin user, */api/auth/admin/adminservice3* returns **401**
- For a non-admin user, */api/auth/admin/thispagedoesntexist* returns 404 ; instead it should return **403**

How can I return the proper authentication code (401/403), when a non-authorized user try to access an non-existing page into a restricted folder ? Custom filter ? HandlerExceptionResolver ?

Comment: Your configuration is in the wrong order. The `intercept-url` patterns need to be listed from most specific to least (the opposite of what you have). If you are running with it as it stands, there should be no access checks at all. Please edit your question to make sure the configuration is what you are actually using. I would also drop the `auto-config` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Luke Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241990/luke-taylor) , my intercept-url are in the wrong order :

```
<http 
    create-session="stateless" 
    realm="Protected API"
    use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/auth/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/auth/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />       
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <http-basic/>   
</http>
```