# Spring Security - Error using @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") results in 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I am having issue using @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") annotation. My controller code is as below which has method welcome() which can only be accessed by user having role ADMIN:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/auth")
public class TestController {


    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome!!!";
    }
}
```

Below is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

AuthEntryPointJwt class is as below:

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

This is the url I am using: http://localhost:8080/user/auth/welcome and this is response

```
{
    "message": null,
    "httpStatusCode": 404,
    "errorLevelCode": "0x2",
    "errorMessage": "Access is denied",
    "apiPath": null,
    "httpMethod": null
}
```

So, I am sending jwt Bearer + token in Authorization header using postman and it is throwing 404. It should have returned resource with token after sending authorization header. I am not able to figure out what the problem is. It would be great to have some suggestion or to know something that I am doing wrong over here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the controller, with spring security disabled ? Does this work ? Sometimes spring security returns 404, if e.g. an error-page is not found (depends on your config), which should be forwarded to, in case of 401/403 error. I experienced similiar, when using spring 3. Not sure, if this is still valid in spring 4/5. Also make sure, that your bearer token is not expired.

Comment: This works fine when I remove @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") @lunatikz

Comment: looks similar like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429124/spring-security-preauthorize-returns-404, have you seen that ? maybe give the last answer a try..

Comment: @bharatsingh Error message says: *Access is denied*, that means your user hasn't the role `ADMIN`. You have to give your user the authority `ROLE_ADMIN`.  Also you probably get 404 instead of 403 because your `unauthorizedHandler` isn't handling the 403 in the right way.

Comment: @dur I added prefix ROLE_ in my roles enum and now it works when I send token on Authorization header but it still throws 404 when it is not authorized. It should be throwing 401 right?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I have added AuthEntryPointJwt class. Can you suggest what  proper configuration for endpoints should be like? Any link would be good help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the property `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in your `application.properties` so we can see what Spring Security is doing

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 suggest that you have problem with endpoint mapping (no resource found in path). If it was security issue you would get error 401 (unauthorized) or error 403 (forbidden).

If I am right then you should get same error when you remove @PreAuthorize and add "welcome" path to security config with access "permitAll".